# Guaranteed Small Loan with no assets to pawn and poor credit

Tags: loans, rent

I need to pass the criteria the various loan companies require to receive an emergency loan I will consider all possibilities to get approved for and receive the loan in my name how can I provide qualifying documents and Information to a loan agency to guarantee a small loan approval. I am not beyond manipulating my information a little please help my rent is due

Comment: You’ll need to provide more information about your situation to get a good answer here. What documents are being requested that you don’t have? What is your current income? How much money are you requesting as a loan, and when are you thinking you’ll pay it back?

Comment: I dont have a job I was recently laid off i was averaging about 3000.00 a month from september 2018 to January 15 2019, I have a bank account with 0 dollars in it. The documents that are being requested that i dont have are bank statements or paystubs with a qualifying amount on it

Comment: If you have no income and no savings then frankly a loan is not going to help you.

Comment: it will help me because I am in the process of finding a job and will have one extremely soon I'm an expert job hunter and have I high success rate of landing jobs but I have pressing financial obligations that nee to be resolved faster than the time it would take to earn the money although I will be earning money very soon

Answer (score 1):

Getting a loan from a traditional financial institution is likely impossible for you at this point in your life. (Falsifying loan documents is not an option.) And while that is tough to hear, the silver lining here is that going further into debt would be a mistake; you would be digging yourself further into a hole that will be even harder to climb out of.

Your first priority should be getting a job ASAP.

The United Way has a very good article on [what to do if you are having trouble paying your rent](https://www.unitedway.org/my-smart-money/pages/how-to-cover-your-rent).  Some of the suggestions from that article are:

- Be honest with your landlord about your situation. If you have been a good tenant and have a plan to increase your income, your landlord might be accommodating.
- Do something to lower your housing costs, such as finding a roommate, moving to a cheaper apartment (possibly subsidized), or moving in with family or friends.
- Accept charity. There are welfare and charity programs that provide food and even help pay rent. The article talks about this in more detail, but you can also call 211 or visit [211.org](http://211.org) to find information about charities in your area.